# Oracle regex: \Q\E doesn't work

Tags: regex, oracle, diacritics

I found that `\Q\E` doesn't work in oracle.
What is the equivalent expression of `\Q\E` for oracle regex ?

Comment: Which regex engine supports `\Q\E`?

Comment: Perl and Java, according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#qe .  It escaped the containing characters as literal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but with Java you can do

```
Pattern.quote(yourString);
```

which returns a literal string. So the String `.` would return `\Q.\E`, which would be considered a period by the Matcher.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, `\Q` starts the automatic escaping of special characters and `\E` stops this behaviour. So within a `\Q  \E` block, a dot would be treated as a literal dot rather than any character.

If Oracle doesn't support this, then just escape any special characters that would have been in the block.

Comment: done like you said. its worked. and in java looks terrible :)  
myString.replaceAll( "\\\(", "\\\\\(" ).replaceAll( "\\\)", "\\\\\)"
hope there exists better way

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but still an issue in Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0, and I don't see it addressed elsewhere. So, in case it helps others, my solution is:

> select dummy from dual
>   where REGEXP_LIKE(dummy,REGEXP_REPLACE('X','([]\^.$|()[*+?{},])','\\\1'))